# The integral of a piecewise function

Tags: integration, functions

For each $n \geq 1$, let
\begin{align*}
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $x\in(-\infty,0]$,}\\n^2&\text{if $x\in(0,1/n]$,}\\0&\text{if $x\in(1/n,\infty)$.}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and let
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $x\in(-\infty,0]$,}\\0&\text{if $x\in(0,\infty)$.}\end{cases}
\end{align*}

$f(x)$ is the limit function of $f_n(x)$ but we are told the integrals are different over $[0,\infty)$

I am having trouble computing this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what exactly is troubling you?

Comment: @UmeshShankar $f(x)$ is the limit function of $f_n(x)$ but we are told the integrals are different over $[0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I assume the main properties of the Lebesgue integral are known. In particular, the Lebesgue integral allows you to say that if you integrate a function on a singleton $\{a\}$, then $\int_{\{a\}} f(x) dx = 0$. The main consequence of that is
$$ \forall a,b \in \mathbf{R}, \quad \int_{[a,b)} fdx =  \int_{\{a \}} fdx +\int_{(a,b)} fdx =  \int_{(a,b)} fdx$$.

In your case, $f$ is a positive function, so there is no problem to integrate it on $[0, \infty)$. You have
$$ \int_{[0, \infty)} f(x) dx = \int_{\{0\}} f(x) dx +  \int_{(0, \infty)} f(x) dx.$$
As the set $\{0\}$ is a singleton, you have $$\int_{\{0\}} f(x) dx = 0.$$
Furthermore $$\int_{(0, \infty)} f(x) dx = \int_{(0, \infty)} 0 dx = 0.$$

Then  $\int_{[0, \infty)} f(x) dx = 0$

In a similar way, you can compute $\int_{[0, \infty)} f_n(x) dx$ by writing
$$ \int_{[0, \infty)} f_n(x) dx = \int_{\{0\}} f_n(x) dx + \int_{(0,1/n)} f_n(x) dx + \int_{\{1/n\}} f_n(x) dx+ \int_{(1/n, \infty)} f_n(x) dx$$
If you remove the integrals on singletons, you have
$$ \int_{[0, \infty)} f_n(x) dx = \int_{(0,1/n)} f_n(x) dx + \int_{(1/n, \infty)} f_n(x) dx$$
Then
$$ \int_{[0, \infty)} f_n(x) dx = \int_{(0,1/n)} n^2  dx + \int_{(1/n, \infty)} 0 dx = n$$.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have an (integrable) function $f$ defined on an interval $I=[a,b]$, and suppose you have $g$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in I$ but finitely many. Then $g$ is still integrable and $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b g(x)dx$.

Now your function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ is the zero function except at one point where it is equal to one, hence the integral of $f$ will coincide with that of the zero function, that is $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=0$.

Now for $f_n$ you could split your integral into two parts i.e. : \begin{align*} \int_0^\infty f_n(x)dx &= \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x)dx + \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^\infty f_n(x)dx
\end{align*}
The first integral is easy to calculate and the second as well using the same idea as above for $f$.